# knockout subscription not working

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have been trying to subscribe to when a dropdown value changes. I have the following logic however I cannot seem to get it working.

**HTML**

```
            <div id="case-pin-@modelItem.CaseID" data-caseid="@modelItem.CaseID" class="row hidden popovercontainer pinBinding">
                <select data-bind="options:userPins,
                        value:selectedPin,
                        optionsCaption:'-- please select --',
                        optionsText: 'Name',
                        optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
            </div>
```

**JS**

```
function UserPinViewModel(caseId) {
    var self = this;
    self.selectedPin = ko.observable();
    self.userPins = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.caseId = caseId;

    self.selectedPin.subscribe(function (newValue) {
        console.log(newValue);
        //addCaseToPin(newValue, self.caseId);
    });
}

var pinObjs = [];

$(function () {
    pinObjs = [];

    $(".pinBinding").each(function () {
        var caseId = this.getAttribute("data-caseid");
        var view = new UserPinViewModel(caseId);
        pinObjs.push(view);

        ko.cleanNode(this);
        ko.applyBindings(view, this);
    });
})
```

The userPins array is populated by an AJAX call to the server as the values in the dropdown are dependent upon another section of the website which can change the values in the dropdown - here the logic I have used to populate the array.

```
function getPins() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Home/GetPins',
        success: function (data) {
                for (var i = 0; i < pinObjs.length; i++) {
                    pinObjs[i].userPins(data);
                }
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            alert("Oooopppppsss! Something went wrong - " + error);
        }
    });
}
```

The actual values in the dropdowns all change to match what is returned from the server however whenever I manually change the dropdown, the subscription event is not fired.

Comment: so you dont get anything on console.log? can you post fiddle?

Comment: It works here https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/39/

Comment: Yes - I too having it working in isolation in a fiddle however with the exact same logic, it doesn't work in the main app it is implemented in

Answer (score 0):

You're using both jQuery and Knockout to manipulate the DOM, which is not a good idea. The whole idea of Knockout is that you don't manipulate the DOM, it does. You manipulate your viewModel.

Using `cleanNode` is also a code smell, indicating that you're doing things the wrong way. Knockout will handle that if you use the tools Knockout provides.

In this case, I was going to suggest a custom binding handler, but it looks like all you really want is to have a `UserPinViewModel` object created and applied to each instance of your `.pinBinding` element in the HTML. You can do that using the [`with` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/with-binding.html), if you expose the `UserPinViewModel` constructor in your viewModel.

```js
function UserPinViewModel(caseId) {
  var self = this;
  self.selectedPin = ko.observable();
  self.userPins = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.caseId = caseId;

  self.selectedPin.subscribe(function(newValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
    //addCaseToPin(newValue, self.caseId);
  });

  // Pretend Ajax call to set pins
  setTimeout(() => {
    self.userPins([{
      Name: 'option1',
      Id: 1
    }, {
      Name: 'option2',
      Id: 2
    }, {
      Name: 'option3',
      Id: 3
    }])
  }, 800);

  // Later, the options change
  setTimeout(() => {
    self.userPins([{
      Name: 'animal1',
      Id: 'Elephant'
    }, {
      Name: 'animal2',
      Id: 'Pony'
    }, {
      Name: 'animal3',
      Id: 'Donkey'
    }])
  }, 4000);

}

ko.bindingHandlers.pin = {
  init: () => null,
  update: () => null
};

ko.applyBindings({
  pinVm: UserPinViewModel
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div id="case-pin-@modelItem.CaseID" data-bind="with: new pinVm('someCaseId')" class="row hidden popovercontainer pinBinding">
  <select data-bind="options:userPins,
                     value:selectedPin,
                     optionsCaption:'-- please select --',
                     optionsText: 'Name',
                     optionsValue: 'Id'"></select>
</div>
```

Your `getPins` function suggests that the `.pinBinding` elements should correspond to the data being received. In that case, `pinObjs` should really be a part of your viewModel, and the elements should be generated (perhaps in a [`foreach`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)) from the data, rather than being hard-coded. I don't know how that works with what I presume is the server-side `@modelItem.CaseID`, though.

Comment: Thanks for that - just out of curiosity, with the loading of the array taking place inside of the view model, how would this support changing the array on the fly as I do with my getPins function - as the array can and will most likely change meaning the dropdown values will need to be updated to reflect the change?

Comment: Maybe I should have made the time delay a little longer, but when my snippet starts, there are no options in the list. 8/10 second later, they get loaded. If you change them again, they'll change in the DOM. That's Knockout doing what it does. I'll update the snippet to change a couple times.

Comment: Thanks Roy - but frustratingly as your fiddle and my own work in isolation, the subscription event is still not firing in the app - back to the drawing board I think now!

Comment: Make sure you haven't re-assigned the variable after making the subscription. It's a common mistake to do `self.selectedPin = something` instead of `self.selectedPin(something)`, and it would throw away the subscription with the observable.